# How to countByValue in Pyspark with duplicate key?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get all unique values of the RDD and their respective occurrence counts. I tried to convert list of elements to RDD and trying to get the occurrence of each value.

```
X_RDD = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,4,2,1,1,1,1,1])
Y_MAP = X_RDD.map(lambda m:(m,1))
for i in Y_MAP.countByValue():print(i)
```

I got the below output:

```
8,1
7,1
6,1
5,1
4,1
3,1
2,1
1,1
```

How I can get the occurrences like below:

```
1,6
2,3
3,1
4,2
5,1
6,1
7,1
8,1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**countByValue():** It return the count of each unique value in this RDD as a dictionary of (value, count) pairs and to access this dictionary, you need `.items()`. This part you were missing.

**Method 1:** Mirrors your method

```
sorted(sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,4,2,1,1,1,1,1]).countByValue().items())
    [(1, 6), (2, 3), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 1)]
```

**Method 2:** It's more elementary.

```
X_RDD = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,4,2,1,1,1,1,1])
Y_MAP = X_RDD.map(lambda m:(m,1))

x = Y_MAP.groupByKey().mapValues(lambda x:list(x))
x.mapValues(lambda x:len(x)).collect()
    [(1, 6), (2, 3), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 1)]
```